# Objective-c how to implement a "Goal seek" like algorithm, similar to excel?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, algorithm, recursion

I have a rather complicated equation with a single variable that I would like to vary. T**he goal is to get the equation to equal 0.**

For example:

```
0 = variable * (complicated equation of constants and exponents)
```

My initial thought was to simply brute force down from some large enough value of variable, but I quickly realized that the number I'm "Goal seeking" may contain a fractional component, so simple integer decrement may not work.

Can someone suggest the correct "Goal seek" algorithm implementation, like excel?

```
double result = 1;
double variable = 1000;
double tempVariable = variable;
double tolerance = 0.1;

while (abs(result) > tolerance ) {
    variable--;

    result = variable * (complicated equation);

};
```

Is there an algorithm I can use to numerically solve the equation that I have?

Comment: Knowing the 'complicated equation' might help.

Answer (score 1):

[Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is a commonly used technique.  In this case you'd want to minimize the absolute value of your complicated function, which would find the closest value to 0.

Comment: If the equation could be fitted into a curve, then we may interpolate and find the solution much faster than Simulated Annealing. It depends on the nature of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use least square curve fitting (see "lsqcurvefit" in MATLAB). lsqcurvefit is much more powerful than GoalSeek in curve-fitting depending on the complexity of the problem to solve.

cheers,